# sqlite primary key in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to set default id for my table but I want to set my first id = M1 and another id increment and template from id number one and set it as primary key. How to do that?

```
id      NAME
M1      ALEX
M2      JAK
M3      LILOMN
M4       .
.        .
```

Comment: where is code, very vague

Comment: id  clumns like this :  M1   M2  M3   M4  M5

Comment: Add M to the id when you fetch data from db

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your ID must be an integer and set to auto increment have a look at this tutorial